# How to nest unboxed vectors?

Tags: arrays, haskell, vector

This may be a pretty basic question, but I've searched around and I cannot seem to find the answer.

I would like to represent a 2D list using unboxed Vectors. This is easily done with normal vectors:

```
> import qualified Data.Vector as V
> V.fromList [V.fromList [1..5]]
[[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

But if I try with unboxed vectors:

```
> import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
> U.fromList [U.fromList [1..5]]
```

I get the following error:

```
• Non type-variable argument
    in the constraint: U.Unbox (U.Vector a)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a.
          (U.Unbox (U.Vector a), U.Unbox a, Num a, Enum a) =>
          U.Vector (U.Vector a)
```

I suspect it has something to do with this:

```
> V.fromList [1..5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

whereas

```
> U.fromList [1..5]
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

But I can't seem to understand how to avoid this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use `V.Vector (U.Vector a)`. That still gives you most of the performance advantage of unboxed vectors, provided the inner vectors aren't very small. Alternatively, if the inner vectors are _always the same, small size_, use an unboxable fixed-size type, e.g. from the [linear package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear).

Answer (score 5):

Well, we can start following the suggestion given by the compiler:

```
> :set -XFlexibleContexts
```

However:

```
> U.fromList [U.fromList [1..5]]

<interactive>:10:1: error:
    • No instance for (U.Unbox (U.Vector a0))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
```

The issue here is the you can't unbox a vector (even if it's of unboxed data). To unbox a data type, you need to describe the byte layout precisely, including its size. But a vector does not have a size. Consider e.g.

```
U.fromList [U.fromList [1..5], U.fromList [1..7]]
```

Even in C, this would require a ["jagged" matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), usually represented with pointers (= boxing).

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be possible to define an `Unbox a => Unbox (U.Vector a)` instance, whose vectors would be based on one flat array of values and one array of start-indices for the inner vectors. That should give decent performance for pure operations.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That might be possible, I think. I am not familiar enough with the `Unboxed` implementation to estimate if that would work nicely. (For instance, I just realized that the `Unbox` class has actually no fields.)

Comment: `Unbox a` is basically a synonym for `(G.Vector U.Vector a, GM.MVector U.MVector a)`. What's needed is a definition of `basicUnsafeSlice` etc.. And as I said, it appears that the [`Vector` interface](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#t:Vector) could be nicely defined with a flattened-regions approach. [`MVector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Generic-Mutable-Base.html#t:MVector) is where it gets hairy.